# Could these "if statements" be simplified?

Tags: java, string

I have the following method:

```
public static String format_String(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{   
    if(hours > 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds > 0) return hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds.";
    else if(hours > 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds == 0) return hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes.";
    else if(hours > 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds > 0) return hours + " hours and " + seconds + " seconds.";
    else if(hours > 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) return hours + " hours.";
    else if(hours == 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds > 0) return minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds.";
    else if(hours == 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds == 0) return minutes + " minutes.";
    else //if(hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds > 0)
    return seconds + " seconds.";
}
```

Can this method be simplified?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: It could be better named too! :P

Comment: @rsp Of course yes, but HOW?!

Comment: You're missing the condition that all of the arguments are 0. Your else is covering two combinations.

Comment: Possibly not.  "0 seconds" is a perfectly valid fall-back in my mind.  The case he's really missing is 1 second, or 1 hour, or 1 minute, in which case it'll pluralise.  Silly pluralisation.

Comment: @Greg Sorry, I didn't mentioned that in my program cannot be all zeros together

Comment: @Jeff Yes the grammar works but the comment suggested this case hadn't been considered. Was just pointing it out. Turns out it had been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tricky part is whether to separate parts with `" and "` or `","`, which depends on how many non-zero parts appear to the right of the part you are currently printing.  The rest (printing the names and numbers) is easy.

Hence you can reduce the number of branches by building the string from right-to-left.

```
public static String format_String(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(".");
    String sep = "", nextSep = " and ";
    if (seconds > 0) {
        result.insert(0, " seconds").insert(0, seconds);
        sep = nextSep;
        nextSep = ", ";
    }
    if (minutes > 0) {
        result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " minutes").insert(0, minutes);
        sep = nextSep;
        nextSep = ", ";
    }
    if (hours > 0) {
        result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " hours").insert(0, hours);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

or more generally:

```
public static String formatString(SortedMap<TimeUnit, Integer> parts) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(".");
    String sep = "", nextSep = " and ";
    for (Map.Entry<TimeUnit, Integer> e: parts.entrySet()) {
        TimeUnit field = e.getKey();
        Integer quantity = e.getValue();
        if (quantity > 0) {
            result.insert(0, sep)
                  .insert(0, field.toString().toLowerCase())
                  .insert(0, ' ')
                  .insert(0, quantity);
            sep = nextSep;
            nextSep = ", ";
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of how you would prepare to SAY the same sentence.

```
if hours > 0 then say the hours
if minutes > 0 then say the minutes
if seconds > 0 then say the seconds
```

Then create the logic using a StringBuilder with a single return at the end.

Comment: You still need to insert the punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator to make it a little less verbose:

```
return
(hours > 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds > 0)   ? hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds." :
(hours > 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds == 0)  ? hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes." :
(hours > 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds > 0)  ? hours + " hours and " + seconds + " seconds." :
(hours > 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) ? hours + " hours." :
(hours == 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds > 0)  ? minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds." :
(hours == 0 && minutes > 0 && seconds == 0) ? minutes + " minutes." :
seconds + " seconds.";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public static String formatTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    if (hours > 0) parts.add(hours + " hours");
    if (minutes > 0) parts.add(minutes + " minutes");
    if (parts.isEmpty() || seconds > 0) parts.add(seconds + " seconds");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0) builder.append((i < parts.size() - 1) ? ", " : " and " );
        builder.append(parts.get(i));
    }

    return builder.append(".").toString();
}
```

It's more scalable. I only question if it's readable among new-to-Java developers.

Comment: Seems like it's more scalable...you could expand this to include days, weeks, months, etc.

Comment: It's not easy to read, but neither are any of the other solutions.

Comment: @BalusC You could optimize further by initializing the size of the ArrayList to 3.

Comment: @Michael: Fair point, but that's microoptimization. It's eligible for GC already when you return from the method.

Comment: @BalusC Oh and you need to do `builder.append('.'); return builder.toString();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all values will always be >= 0. The code looks more complicated, but there are MANY fewer comparisons!

```
if(hours > 0) {
    if(minutes > 0) {
        if(seconds > 0) return hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds.";
        return hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes.";
    }
    if(seconds > 0) return hours + " hours and " + seconds + " seconds.";
    return hours + " hours.";
}
if(minutes > 0 ) {
    if(seconds > 0 ) return minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds.";
    return minutes + " minutes.";
}
return seconds + " seconds.";
```